# Prove that $\mathbb{R}^3 \backslash P$ is not simply connected

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, differential-topology, differential-forms

For $P=\{y=x^2,z=0\}$, I need to prove that $\mathbb{R}^3 \backslash P$ is not simply connected by showing that there exists $\alpha$ such that $\int_S \alpha \neq 0$ for the circle $\{y^2+z^2=1,x=0 \}$.

My attempt is to use
$$\alpha = \frac{zdy-ydz}{z^2+y^2}$$
but to do this I need to find a diffeomorphism that transforms the parabola defined by $P$ to the line $y=0$. This is where I'm stuck.

Please help!

Comment: Hello :) Actually, you mean the line $y=z=0$, right? Maybe, you can map every point $(t,t^2,0)$ to $(t,0,0)$?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! <> This isn't exactly your issue, but may be close enough to help. If $f$ is a smooth, real-valued function of one variable, the mapping $F(x, y) = (x, y - f(x))$ is a diffeomorphism of the plane mapping the graph of $f$ to the line $y = 0$.